# Waking upon restart a Thunderbolt Display connected to a CalDigit TS3 Plus dock to a MBP in closed-clamshell mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, dock, thunderbolt-display

When I have a Thunderbolt Display connected directly to my 2018 MacBook Pro 15" in closed-clamshell mode and I restart the MBP, the Thunderbolt Display will of course turn on so that I can see that I need to enter my login password at the FileVault 2 login screen. But when I restart with a CalDigit TS3 Plus dock in-between the TD and the MacBook Pro, my Thunderbolt Display remains dark until I lift the lid of the MBP and enter the FV2 login password (the internal display of course illuminates immediately after I lift the lid). Then with the lid closed again and a bit later in the boot sequence, the TD turns on.

Is an inactive display at the FileVault 2 login when it is connected through a Thunderbolt 3 dock? The folks at CalDigit say it isn't.

Comment: I've already tried a replacement TS3 Plus with the same results.

Comment: Same results with a Targus Thunderbolt dock